# c# , Linq, Select and Count

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, count

I am learning c#. The following code prints out 5. I am quite confused about how Select works. Shouldn't the result be 2, as the 2nd and 3rd word in sequence 1 are shorter than corresponding words in sequence 2? Can someone please help to explain? Many thanks in advance!

```
string[] seq1 = { "jumps", "over", "pop", "milk", "egg", }; 
string[] seq2 = { "jam", "dizzy", "fuzzy", "the" };
var count = seq1.Select( n1 => seq2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length) ) .Count();
```

Comment: what do you want your code to do? you say you want the result to be 2, but from the code provided I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: No I dont, and that's my question. I am confused about how the code works.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. I am only trying to understand the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It counts all elements from `seq1` (so it is just like `seq1.Count()`

this is de-Linq-ued code of yours:

```
string[] seq1 = { "jumps", "over", "pop", "milk", "egg", };
string[] seq2 = { "jam", "dizzy", "fuzzy", "the" };
var count = 0;
foreach (string n1 in seq1)
{
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = seq2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length);
    count++;
}
```

Your code `Selects` items from `seq2` that are shorter than current element from `seq` but does nothing with them. To achieve comparing "corresponding" items, you can run this snippet

```
string[] seq1 = { "jumps", "over", "pop", "milk", "egg", };
string[] seq2 = { "jam", "dizzy", "fuzzy", "the" };

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(seq1.Length,seq2.Length); i++)
{
    if (seq1[i].Length < seq2.Length) count++;
}
```

it will check if "corresponding" items are longer in second sequence

EDIT:

changing to `SelectMany` will make it iterate through seq2 also

```
foreach (string n1 in seq1)
    foreach (string s in seq2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length))
        count++;
```

Comment: @user3735871 you can check de-linq-ued code for SelectMany

Comment: I only knew that SelectMany "flatten" the list. I couldn't figure out how it also iterate through seq2.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does this:

for every item in sequent 1, select

```
seq1.Select( n1 =>
```

A collection of sequence 2 elements that are shorter than the sequent 1 element.

```
seq2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length)
```

then count the number of sequence 2 collectionS you have (ie 5 - one for each sequence 1 element)

```
) .Count();
```

Comment: nope, it counts only elements from `seq1`. It does nothing with `seq2` elements. It is no more than `seq1.Count()`

Comment: er, yup. The select returns a collection of sequence 2 elements for every sequence 1 element. this collection may well be empty, but it's still a collection that gets counted. As per your comment edit we agree that it effectively just counts sequence 1 elements.

Comment: `seq1` is counted, if you do `seq1.Select(n1=>n1).Count()` result will be the same, all select body is unnecessary

Comment: I totally agree. Where do I say otherwise?

Comment: @wudzik Thanks! but if I change Select to SelectMany, why does the result becomes 8? I mean if it only counts seq1 ?

Comment: Because SelectMany() is used to merge multiple selections into one big selection. As per my answer, you are creating multiple sequence 2 collections. The SelectMany() will put items from all those collections into one big collectiion, so you count is now counting items in that collection, rather than counting the number of collectionS

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer What would be that big collect SelectMany returns? could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

No. With `seq2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length)` you filter elements comparing sizes, but with `seq1.Select(...)` you do this for every Element of seq1. With this you get a list of lists. The `Select()` Function is a projection not a filter.

In your example this results in the following:
`

n1 = "jumps" => [],

n1 = "over" => ["dizzy", "fuzzy"],

n1 = "pop" => ["dizzy", "fuzzy"],

n1 = "milk" => ["dizzy", "fuzzy"],

n1 = "egg" => ["dizzy", "fuzzy"]`

As you can see, you have 5 elements each containing parts from seq2.

Comment: Thanks! But if I change Select to SelectMany, the result becomes 8. What does the .Count do in this case?

Comment: With .SelectMany you collect all elements of each inner result into one list. In this example this would result in the following list:
["dizzy", "fuzzy", "dizzy", "fuzzy", "dizzy", "fuzzy", "dizzy", "fuzzy"]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but have a look at this:
seq2.Where(n2 => seq2.Any(n1 => n1.Length < n2.Length))

This results in all the elements of seq2 where there is at least one element in seq1, which is shorter.
In the example this would result in
["dizzy", "fuzzy"]

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).ASPX) doesn't filter the input sequence like [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx). That's why you get 5 as result. The array `seq1` contains 5 words and you're selecting from this array. It doesn't matter what you select, because - as already said - `Select` doesn't filter.

You can use this:

```
int count = seq1
    .Where((n1, index1) => seq2.Length > index1 && n1.Length < seq2[index1].Length)
    .Count();
```

Here is a different approach using `Zip` + `Sum`:

```
int count = seq1.Zip(seq2, (n1, n2) => n1.Length < n2.Length ? 1 : 0).Sum();
```